# Static Analyzer says I have a leak....why?

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, clang-static-analyzer

I think this code should be fine but Static Analyzer doesn't like it. I can't figure out why and was hoping that someone could help me understand. The code works fine, the analyzer result just bugs me.

```
Coin *tempCoin = [[Coin alloc] initalize];
self.myCoin = tempCoin;
[tempCoin release];
```

`Coin` is a generic `NSObject` and it has an initalize method. `myCoin` is a property of the current view and is of type `Coin`. I assume it is telling me I am leaking `tempCoin`.

In my view's .h I have set myCoin as a property with nonatomic,retain.

I've tried to autorelease the code as well as this normal release but Static Analyzer continues to say:
1. Method returns an Objective-C object with a +1 retain count (owning reference)
2. Object allocated on line 97 is no longer referenced after this point and has a retain count of +1 (object leaked)

Line 97 is the first line that I show.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because the static analyzer is looking for `init`, not `initialize`. It sees the latter and assumes that the object returned by `[Coin alloc]` returns a different object from `initialize`, thus leaking the first object.

Change the name of the method to `init` and the static analyzer will no longer report a leak.

Comment: Thanks. That did it. Ahhhhh...code that compiles with no warnings.